# Applications and browsers don't resolve .co.il hostnames, while dig/nslookup does

Tags: networking, dns

A weird problem I have for some time:

Quite often, yet not consistently, when I boot my Ubuntu 17.04 machine, I can't browse Israeli sites (I'm in Israel myself). Any hostname in the co.il TLD doesn't get resolved by browsers and other applications such as ping, while dig/nslookup resolves them perfectly.

Usually (yet not always) what fixes the problem is adding the Google DNS servers to /etc/resolv.conf.
I have added these nameservers to /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/ yesturday, so that I don't have to manually add them every time, but today I have booted Ubuntu, and .co.il domains do not resolve.

Some commands and files that might be of interest:

```
$ ping google.co.il
ping: google.co.il: Name or service not known
```

,

```
$ dig google.co.il

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> google.co.il
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 59430
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.co.il.          IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.co.il.       299 IN  A   216.58.205.227

;; Query time: 78 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sat Aug 12 11:27:04 IDT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 57
```

,

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf  
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

,

```
$ cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

,

```
$ systemd-resolve --status
Global
         DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8
                      8.8.4.4
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (enp3s0)
      Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes
         DNS Servers: 10.0.0.138
          DNS Domain: Home
```

What can it be?

Thanks.

Comment: I assume you are using -desktop, not -server, right? My suspicion is that you entered search domains in NetworkManager incorrectly (you need to enter them one at a time, with Add), and that's messing up the systemd-resolver, which is too proud to consider rejecting invalid input.

what does `systemd-resolve --status` show?

Comment: I didn't add anything to the seached domains anywhere as far as I can recall.  Added output of `systemd-resolve --status` to the post. Don't see anything suspicious there.

Comment: what is 10.0.0.138 that you are using as a DNS server? Where/how did you set that one up? That's what the systemd resolver is using.

Comment: That's my router. I got it from DHCP.